# How can I build this JSON in JAVA?

Tags: java, json

I need to build that json in java and do not know how since it has many parentheses.

```
  [{
    "id": "52350f7bbc39dd030800007e",
    "quantity": 2
},{
    "id": "52352e7ebc39ddc8ef0000c7",
    "quantity": 2,
    "selections": [{
                    "id": "52352e7ebc39ddc8ef0000c8",
                    "item_ids":[
                                "52352e7ebc39ddc8ef0000c9",
                                "52352e7ebc39ddc8ef0000ca"
                                ]
                   }]
}]
```

Comment: I do not understand your question. What have you tried ? What did not go well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two classes as below :

Raw struture :

```
Class JsonEx
{
String id;
String quantity;
List<Selection> selection;
}

Class Selection
{
String id;
List<String> item_ids;
}
```

Set the attributes to the `JsonEx` class including `Selection` too and thn use GSON to create json as below:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
// convert java object to JSON format,
// and returned as JSON formatted string
String json = gson.toJson(JsonEx obj);
```

Comment: For various reasons I had to create the object with the following attributes "private String _id; 
private int _quantity; 
private String _description; 
private String _name; 
private int _price; 
private List <SelectionShoppingCart> _selections ". GSON creates the JSON with all the attributes, how can selleccionar who really need?

Comment: r u facing some pblm with such attribute ??

Comment: http://camelcode.org/tutorial/Exclude-fields-from-JSON-using-Gson-with-@Expose.htm ojojojo here is the solution to my question